# Min size with aspect ratio resize image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm doing a resize function over an image using this code:

```
$('.image_resize').each(function(){
    var ww = $(window).width() - 80 - 400;
    var wh = $(window).height() - 60;
    var iar = $(this).attr('height') / $(this).attr('width');
    var war = wh / ww;
    if(iar <= war){
        $(this).attr("width" , ww);
        $(this).attr("height" , ww * iar);
    }else{
        $(this).attr("height" , wh);
        $(this).attr("width" , wh / iar);
    }
})
```

this markup:

```
<div id="home_image">
    <img class="image_resize" src="img/home_image.jpg" alt="home_image" width="945" height="557">
</div>
```

The code works nice and resize the image with the correct aspect ratio, but the problem is that **there is no minium limit to that resize, so the image can became as small as 20 pixel * ratio and I want to limit that.**

How can limit the image to just say to a minium height of 400px and cropping the container over it, or any thing like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things to consider here:

1) The size of the image is restricted by ww and wh. You may wish to specify a minimum width and height for the area the image.

```
var ww = $(window).width() - 80 - 400;
var wh = $(window).height() - 60;
ww= ww<50 ? 50 : ww;
wh= wh<50 ? 50 : wh;
```

2) The size of the image is also affected by it's aspect ratio. So lets say you have a panoramic image - above code will make sure that the minimum width is 50 pixels, but it's height might only be 15 px because of its aspect ratio. If you want to enforce a minimal height in those cases, you'll have to change the code withing your conditional blocks. Please note that this will also change the actual width to be much wider than ww limits it to.

```
if(iar <= war){
    if (ww*iar<50) { 
        $(this).attr("width" , 50 / iar);
        $(this).attr("height" , 50);
    } else {
        $(this).attr("width" , ww);
        $(this).attr("height" , ww * iar);
    }
}else{
    if (wh*iar<50) {
        $(this).attr("height" , 50 * iar);
        $(this).attr("width" , 50);
    } else {
        $(this).attr("height" , wh);
        $(this).attr("width" , wh / iar);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by simply checking if window height is less than 400. If it is then force it to be 400 using following code.

```
var wh = $(window).height() - 60;
wh = wh < 400 ? 400 : wh;
```